# How to crash RabbitMQ node forcefully without stopping it gracefully?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am learning RabbitMQ but I could not crash a rabbitmq node without stopping it.

In the following image second node is showing red with the message **"Node not running"** as it is stopped gracefully.

[image]

How to make the first node, red/crash by keeping it running?

Comment: on a linux you can kill rabbitmq process